# jquery countdown pause and resume feature?

Tags: jquery, countdown

i need to code to pause and resume jquery countdown .
for this script:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-countdown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the plugin's `stop` function, like this:

```
<span id="count">8</span>
<input type="button" id="pause" value="Pause" />
<input type="button" id="resume" value="Resume" />
```

And the js:

```
function start() {
    $('#count').countdown({seconds: parseInt($('#count').text())});
}
function pause() {
    $('#count').countdown.stop();
}
$('#pause').click(pause);
$('#resume').click(start);
start();
```

Look at it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/xHtZV/).

Answer (score 5):

With this plugin is very simple

http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

```
$('#pauseButton').toggle(
    function() { 
        $(this).text('Resume'); 
        $('#pauseResume').countdown('pause'); 
    }, 
    function() { 
        $(this).text('Pause'); 
        $('#pauseResume').countdown('resume'); 
    } 
);
```

Comment: This is the correct code for the latest version of the jQuery Countdown plugin. (As of this comment, which is 2.0.2).